# Unable to set up cron job in magento 2.1.4. cpanel

Tags: magento-2.1, cron, crontab

I am unable to setup cron job. I have installed Magento CE 2.1.4 and had tried to setup cron job through cpanel.

I have used this command for cronjob :

```
* * * * * wget  -o  -q http://www.domain.com/public_html/cron.php
```

I keep getting this error in mail :

```
/bin/bash: /dev/: Is a directory
```

Please help. I am new to magento and am unable to understand how to set it up and also how to set success messages to my mail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to run Magento 2 cron in the same method as Magento 1.x which is the issue. Magento 2 requires the following 3 commands to run in a production environment:

```
php /home/example/example.com/html/bin/magento cron:run

php /home/ example/example.com/html/update/cron.php

php /home/example/example.com/html/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

php is referencing the php user for the store. Make sure the update "/home/example..." with the local environment.

Magento's full documentation on cron setup can be found at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html